# Does IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>.PullAsync pull items that are already in the local table?

Tags: synchronization, azure-mobile-services, offline-mode

I can test this when I have some time but I thought I would ask the question in case anyone else is wondering the same thing.

When you issue a `PullAsync` on a `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>`, is the table smart enough to compare the `__updatedAt` or `__version` columns on the server with the local data so it doesn't pull items that are already present in local storage? If it is, then I can issue pulls without worrying about redundant
data transfers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PullAsync, when passed a query key will do an incremental update, which means it will get all records modified since the last time Pull was called.  (Using a filter on the __updatedAt column)  Version will only be used on the individual operations (update/delete/etc) to detect conflicts.

Without a query key, it will pull all records that match the given query.

Comment: This can be found in documentation, but it doesn't clearly answer the question. If there are multiple devices (and users), should queryID be different for every device/user or API is smart enough to manage that? It is extremely basic question with no proper answer anywhere...

Comment: The queryid is a device side concept only, so no need to make a truly unique key across devices.  Within the instance of the app, your key should be unique based on the query filtering keys. 

So if you just want all records, or only ever use 1 query for that table, you could just have 1 key "all". if you pulled 2 types of queries from a record say leaderboard

Comment: If instead you have 2 different queries on a table (one where user = X and one where user = Y) then each one should have its own key.